# Invalid \x Escape with Byte Notation

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I can't seem to resolve the following pylint error, I checked all the usual suspects and historical Stack Overflow questions but no answer seemed to fit the bill on this one - any thoughts?:

**(value error) invalid \x escape at position 4**

`variable = b'\xC0\xPR\x89\xE1\xPQ\xRP\xB8\x3B\x00\x00\x00\xCD\x80'`

Comment: Note: Using Python 3.9

Comment: What do you expect ``\xPR`` *to be*? ``\x`` escapes are in hex, that is digits of 0-9 a-f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python Hex escapes only with Hexadecimal characters.

The problems in your variable are `\xPR`, `\xPQ`, `\xRP`.

You can only escape hex values between `\x00` and `\xFF`.
An example is `b"\x41\x42\x43"`.